# Swift throws error when trying to access segmented control index

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im currently learning swift and starting out with my first own calculator.
It all worked with a button to calculate the result, but I wanted to improve it a bit. The UI basically consists of two text fields for the numbers, one segmented control for the operators and one label to display the result. So thats what I want to happen:

Every time I change the segmented control value, a new result should be calculated and displayed.

Error:

[Calculator.MainInterfaceViewController operatorChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXXX
... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator.MainInterfaceViewController operatorChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXXX
*** First throw call stack:
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

My Class:

```
class MainInterfaceViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var ersteZahl: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var zweiteZahl: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ergebnisLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ersteZahl.delegate = self;
    zweiteZahl.delegate = self;
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString
    textField.text = newString as String
    refreshUIElements()
    return false
}

@IBAction func operatorChanged() {
    refreshUIElements()
}


func refreshUIElements() {
    let zahl1 = NSString(string: ersteZahl.text!).doubleValue
    let zahl2 = NSString(string: zweiteZahl.text!).doubleValue

    switch self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        ergebnisLabel.text = "Ergebnis: \(zahl1 + zahl2)"
    case 1:
        ergebnisLabel.text = "Ergebnis: \(zahl1 - zahl2)"
    case 2:
        ergebnisLabel.text = "Ergebnis: \(zahl1 * zahl2)"
    case 3:
        if zahl2 == 0 {
            ergebnisLabel.text = "Error: Cannot divide by 0."
            return
        }
        ergebnisLabel.text = "Ergebnis: \(zahl1 / zahl2)"
    default:
        break
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Where did you call `operatorChanged`? The issue is that your method has no parameter, but the error says that it's calls a method with the same name but with a parameter (there is ":" after it). Did you link it with the Storyboard? If YES, either you rename your `operatorChanged` in order to accept what every IBAction do, a sender, or you relink it in your Storyboard.

Comment: @Larme Yeah I linked it through my Main storyboard. I already tried to relink it. Do you have an idea how to fix it? thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you modified the method after it was autogenerated or tried to manually create it?

`@IBAction's` need a `sender` parameter. Something like this:

```
operatorChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
}
```

Delete the method entirely and ctrl + drag from the storyboard again to the file. If the popup, choose action and give the method a name. Do not modify the method definition after this, or it will cause the same issue.